# Show that the integral operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

*Let $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on $M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, where $M$ is compact (so $f$ is uniformly cont.).
I have to show that $T : C(M) \rightarrow C(M) : Tf := \int_M \frac{1}{|t-\tau|} f(\tau) d\tau$ is bounded in the usual norm on $C(M)$, i.e. $\vert \vert f \vert \vert = \sup_{\tau \in M} f$.*

If the kernel function was continuous, this would be child's play, since it would also be bounded and the rest follows easily enough. However, since $1/|x-y|$ has a singularity, I am unsure of what the proper angle of attack is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean $\int_M\frac1{|t-\tau|}f(t)dt$, or perhaps $\int_M\frac1{|t-\tau|}f(\tau)d\tau$?

Comment: Yes, the last, sorry. My bad. I edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $1/|t|$ locally integrable on $\mathbb R^2$:
using polar coordinates, for suitable $R$

$$  \int_M \frac{1}{|t-\tau|} \; dt \le \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^R dr $$

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: $$\|Tf\|  = \sup_{\tau \in M} \int_M \frac{f(t)}{|t-\tau|}\; dt \le \|f\| \sup_{\tau \in M} \int_{M} \dfrac{dt}{|t-\tau|} $$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.